# SVG fallback for css pseudoelement?

Tags: css, svg

I'm creating a site and I'm adding some decorations in `.svg`, but I know that some browsers cannot display them, and that one should specify a `.png` fallback.

The decoration is added with `:after` pseudoelement. Will this be sufficient to enable a `.png` fallback?

```
.section header h3:after {
    content: url("../images/ornament.svg");
    content: url("../images/ornament.png");
    width: 66px;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -33px;
}
```

Comment: "Will this be sufficient to enable a .png fallback?" Did you not test this yourself?

Comment: I did this with a logo element, but this is pseudo element, so I thought I'd ask here first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .png file must come first.

```
.section header h3:after {
    content: url("../images/ornament.png");
    content: url("../images/ornament.svg");
    width: 66px;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -33px;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

**This will however not solve your fall back problem** and you should look at other options. These include, but are not limited to:

- polyfilling
- conditional statements
- server side image convertion

Comment: no, this won't work. Your code snippet will **always** give PNGs and with my code there will be no images on unsupported browsers, however you will see SVG on supported ones.

Comment: may I know which browsers are you targeting? If its just old versions of IE there is an easy solution for that.

Comment: I don't understand why with your code there wouldn't be any images on unsuported browsers? You did put the png and svg inside, shouldn't that work if a browser cannot get svg?

Comment: I don't think that the client expects his customers to be using IE8. So all the newest browsers should be targeted (Chrome, FF, Safari, IE10, IE11, Opera)

Comment: 1. there won't be any images because the old browsers with replace the first `content` (png) after seeing the second `content` (svg), and not be able to render it.
2. Chrome 31+, FF 31+, Safari 7+, IE 9+, Opera 8 all support rendering of SVGs.

Comment: I have tested this on a local machine.

Comment: true, [with the exception of the new Edge browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=content) others have partial support for `content` property (that usually comes with pseudo elements, as in this case) however [all do support pseudo elements](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3AAfter) and have [partial or no support for SVGs](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg). I guess that's what you were trying to imply.